# Snap.svg работа с группой объектов, отдельно

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, svg, snapsvg

Здравствуйте!
Вопрос такой, загружаю файл svg, как группу объектов, как мне работать отдельно с каждым из них?

```
<html>

<head>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "JS/jquery.js"></script>
    <!--script type = "text/javascript" src = "JS/raphael-min"></script-->
    <script src = "JS/snap.svg.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <svg></svg>
    <div id="f"></div>
    <script>
        var s = Snap("svg");
        var g = s.group();
        var onloadmap = Snap.load("SVGFILES/3k1e-test.svg",function(lf)
        {
            var app_lf = g.append(lf);
            console.log(g);
            app_lf.hover(function(){app_lf.animate({ 'transform' : 'r360,225,225' },4000)},function(){app_lf.animate({ 'transform' : 'r-360,225,225' },4000)});
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

И еще вопрос. В этой строке, почему не могу использовать this вместо app_lf ?

```
app_lf.animate({ 'transform' : 'r360,225,225' },4000)}
```

Помогите,пожалуйста!!)